# Why STL list size() complexity is O(1) in C++11, how it is calculated?

Tags: list, c++11, stl, time-complexity

Shouldn't it be O(n), because to calculate the size of a doubly linked list, we have to traverse it?

Comment: Can you think of an implementation that keeps track of the list's size each time it is modified by operations like insert, remove, merge, clear, etc., so that the time complexity of `size()` will be O(1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a length alongside the elements allows for O(1) `size()`.

The downside of that is that a partial [`splice`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) is O(moved elements) rather than O(1). The partial splice needs to know how many elements were transferred, so that it can update the counts. If it didn't, it would only need to update pointers on the seam elements.

Comment: if you move *all* the elements, you can update from the stored size. so the first overload is O(1). The second overload moves one element, so that too know how to update the counts in O(1)